# Idea for a runnin/rolling median in R

Tags: r, time-series, rolling-computation

I am new here and I would like to get some help.
I have a dataset with a datetime column and a certain value assignt to it
|datetime          |value|
2020-06-15 10:30:00| 3  |
2020-06:15 10:31:00| 1  |

and I need a way to calculate for each minute x, the median of (value in x-5; value in x+5)

any ideas?

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.  In particular questions should include the R code which will generate test input and show the expected output.  I have done it for you this time in the Note at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming DF shown in the Note at the end use either of these (only the second one if you have NA's in your data).

```
library(zoo)

transform(DF, median = rollmedian(value, 11, fill = NA))    
transform(DF, median = rollapply(value, 11, median, fill = NA))
```

giving:

```
              datetime value median
1  2020-06-15 10:30:00     1     NA
2  2020-06-15 10:31:00     2     NA
3  2020-06-15 10:32:00     3     NA
4  2020-06-15 10:33:00     4     NA
5  2020-06-15 10:34:00     5     NA
6  2020-06-15 10:35:00     6      6
7  2020-06-15 10:36:00     7      7
8  2020-06-15 10:37:00     8      8
9  2020-06-15 10:38:00     9      9
10 2020-06-15 10:39:00    10     10
11 2020-06-15 10:40:00    11     NA
12 2020-06-15 10:41:00    12     NA
13 2020-06-15 10:42:00    13     NA
14 2020-06-15 10:43:00    14     NA
15 2020-06-15 10:44:00    15     NA
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(
  datetime = seq(as.POSIXct("2020-06-15 10:30:00"), length = 15, by = "min"), 
  value = 1:15)
```